# Any difference for implementing in the class definition for header only libraries?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm working on a library that is heavily using templates so I decided to make it a header-only library. Since declarations and implementations are in the same file, I can now do both at the same time. So I have a choice between these two styles:

```
// seperate declaration and implementation

template <typename T>
class Klass {
public:
    void do_something();
};

template <typename T>
void Klass<T>::do_something()
{
    // do something
}


// or both at the same time

template <typename T>
class Klass {
public:
    void do_something()
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```

I was wondering if there is a difference between these two for the compiler. If not which one would you recommend as a better practice?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes. I have now changed the example as appropriate.

Comment: @gokcehan Almost. You missed the `template <typename T>` before the out-of-class definition of `do_something`. Which could help answer your question...

Comment: @Angew hmm, ok now I fixed it but I'm still not sure what the answer is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight On the second thought, would it still give me linking errors even if I have header guards?

Comment: Yes, it would give you linker errors. Include guards are for the compiler, not for the linker. You'd have to mark the functions `inline` to silence the linker. As to my comment: you have to repeat the template parameters when the definition is out of class. Imagine you decide to add another template parameter, and have to change all the 40+ out-of-class function definitions...

Comment: @gokcehan Header guards prevent multiple inclusion in a single translation unit. If you include the same header from two translation units (i.e. two cpp files) the compiler would generate an implementation in both of them. Once the linker finds that there are two implementations, it will complain.

Comment: @Angew Second one is a lot easier to write and manage so I should prefer it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So how do people actually manage their header-only libraries? I thought I could have some non-template stuff in my library as well. Do I have to make everything `inline` if I don't want any compiled library object?

Comment: @gokcehan If I remember correctly, when you use the second option from your post, C++ linker will do some magic to avoid creating duplicate implementations.

Comment: You can have multiple definitions of member functions of class templates as long as they are in different translation units and all have the same meaning (the standard spends a whole page detailing exactly what counts as having the same meaning). If `Klass` isn't a template, then the first will give you linker errors unless you make the function `inline`; the second won't because member functions defined in the class definition are implicitly inline.

Comment: @gokcehan Me personally, for any moderately complicated separate the definition from the declaration. In this case, I would have a 'Klass.hpp' that has the class declaration, and 'Klass-inl.hpp' with all the declaration functions. Use define guards and then have `#include "Klass.hpp"` at the beginning of the inl, `"#inlude "Klass-inl.hpp"` at the end of klass.hpp.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight T.C. is right: the only case where you'll get linker errors is when you have specializations (which are definitions in themselves) which you can clear up with inlining the specializations.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams He's talking about templates; OP asked me about non-template members, which he had before the edit.

Comment: @Angew on the other hand, having a single header file with hundreds of lines of code will obscure the interface to the class. Its really more a matter of preference. Personally, I use a rule of thumb of if the function is greater than 5-10 lines, move it to an imp.

Answer (score 2):

If you merge the definition and the implementation you will have problem solving cross/circular dependencies.

---

---

For example:

### 1. Using your second option

***home.hpp***

```
#ifndef HOME_HPP
# define HOME_HPP

# include <string>

# include "human.hpp"

template <typename T>
class   Home
{
public:
  Home()
    :
    color_("white"),
    inhabitant_(this)
  {
  }

  void  set_color(const std::string& color)
  {
    color_ = color;
  }

private:
  std::string   color_;
  Human<T>      inhabitant_;
};

#endif
```

***human.hpp***

```
#ifndef HUMAN_HPP
# define HUMAN_HPP

# include <string>

// Cannot include the other header here because it already includes us
//# include "house.hpp" 

// So we do a forward declaration:
template<typename T>
class Home;

template <typename T>
class   Human
{
public:
  Human(Home<T>* house)
    :
    house_(house)
  {
  }

  void  paint(const std::string& color)
  {
   // Oops, we can't use House in our implementation
   // because it is only forward declared
   //house_->set_color(color); 
  }

private:
  Home<T>*     house_;
};

#endif
```

You cannot use the other object.

---

---

Whereas if you split your implementation in another file:

### 2. Using your first option

***home.hpp***

```
#ifndef HOME_HPP
# define HOME_HPP

# include <string>

# include "human.hpp"

template <typename T>
class   Home
{
public:
  Home();

  void  set_color(const std::string& color);

private:
  std::string   color_;
  Human<T>      inhabitant_;
};

#endif
```

***home.ipp***

```
#ifndef HOME_IPP
# define HOME_IPP

# include "home.hpp"

template<typename T>
Home<T>::Home()
  :
  color_("white"),
  inhabitant_(this)
{
}

template<typename T>
void  Home<T>::set_color(const std::string& color);
{
  color_ = color;
}

#endif
```

***human.hpp***

```
#ifndef HUMAN_HPP
# define HUMAN_HPP

# include <string>

template<typename T>
class Home;

template <typename T>
class   Human
{
public:
  Human(Home<T>* house);

  void  paint(const std::string& color);

private:
  Home<T>*     house_;
};

#endif
```

***human.ipp***

```
#ifndef HUMAN_IPP
# define HUMAN_IPP

# include "human.hpp"
# include "house.ipp"

template<typename T>
Human<T>::Human(Home<T>* house)
  :
  house_(house)
{
}

template<typename T>
void  Human<T>::paint(const std::string& color)
{
 house_->set_color(color); 
}

#endif
```

Things works more smoothly

---

---

### 3. Other considerations

- One could also argue that you should put your code in multiple files for the same reason you don't code your whole project in a single file, just to split things to make them more easy to understand.
- And as a last bonus point, for symmetry with the .hpp/.cpp files, which will silence the perfectionist sleeping deep (very deep for some) inside of each developer :)

Comment: But if the OP has no circular dependencies (and ideally they don't) then the question stands!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed, but you can never be sure that you will not have to introduce one at some point, also the question title starts with "Any difference" which basically means if you found one it is a legit answer ^^
One could also argue that you do this for the same reason you don't code your whole project in a single file, just to split things to make them more easy to understand :)
And as a last bonus point, for symmetry with .hpp/.cpp files, which will silence the perfectionist sleeping deep (very deep for some) inside of each developer :)

Comment: I concur - worth adding that to your answer!